# Идентифицировать единственный сайт интернета, которому разрешено пользоваться webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо делать аутентификацию по ключу или токену.  Когда клиент шлет запрос, он также в заголовке отправляет токен/ключ, и вы уже на сервере можете проверять этот токен/ключ и выдавать соответствующий ответ.

Comment: А можно пример, где вытаскивается токен из запроса?